# can't install aobs-tikz package with miktex windows

Tags: errors

I need to use the aobs-tikz package  so I install it automatically using miktex but when I compile my file I get the error
 "File `aobs-tikz.sty' not found".
so please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: The miktex package is faulty, but the package readme too. The ins doesn't create a sty but only a tikz library.

Comment: but how to fix this ?

Comment: Make a bug report.

Comment: I have used the solution proposed here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows) and it worked for me